# How to handle multiple JSON Object at once using java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am facing problem to handle more than one JSON object(class) at once in Recycler Adapter using Volley. I tried two way to solve this problem but failed to fetch output for my Recycler view.

1st way:- I had created a main class(Parent class) where other JSON class extends the main class and by using main class I called all sub class one by one using polymorphism.
eg:-

Main.java

```
public class Main{

}
```

Model1.java

```
public class Model1 extends Main {

        @SerializedName("$t")
        @Expose
        private String $t;

        public String get$t() {
            return $t;
        }

        public void set$t(String $t) {
            this.$t = $t;
        }

    }
```

Model2.java

```
public class Model2 extends Main {

       @SerializedName("$t")
       @Expose
       private String $t;

       public String get$t() {
           return $t;
       }

       public void set$t(String $t) {
           this.$t = $t;
       }
}

and during call I used
```

Main ref;

((Model1) (ref)).get$t();

((Model2) (ref)).get$t();

```
But, Failed to get all value(Please correct if I am worng in code)

and 2nd way:- Just making all the model class as inner class(static) of the main class and calling using
```

Main.Model1.get$t();

```
But did get output. Please suggest me any other way where I can use to get my expected output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the object like this?

```
{
  "Name": "xxxxx",
  "Age": 27,
  "Parents": [
    {
      "Name": "xxxx",
      "Age": 49
    },
    {
      "Name": "xxxxxx",
      "Age": 45
    }
  ],
  "Location": {
    "Address": "xxxx Sunset Ave.",
    "City": "xxxx"
  }
}
```

You can try to create a model like these.

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    @SerializedName("Name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("Age")
    public String age;

    @SerializedName("Parents")
    public List<Person> parents;

    @SerializedName("Location")
    public Location location;
}
```

Location.java

```
public class Location {
    @SerializedName("Address")
    public String address;

    @SerializedName("City")
    public String city;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my actual question is how to use both class(Person.java & Location.java) at the save time in adpter class. Means I want to fetch data from their at the same time for my view.